# How to combine filter and mapping in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, filter, higher-order-functions, map-function

I'm making some exercises with haskell. My Task is to create a list of squares of even numbers without 0 from the list `[0..10]`.

I already made it with the list comprehension in Haskell (Take a look in the code block below.) but now my task is to implement this with the function `map` and `filter` .

```
List comprehension in Haskell:
[x^2 | x <- [0..10], mod x 2==0, x/=0]


f = (\x -> (x^2))
p = (\x -> mod x 2 == 0 && x/=0)

map1 :: (a->b) -> [a] -> [b]
map1 f [] = []
map1 f (x:xs) = f x : map1 f xs

filter1 :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter1 p [] = []
filter1 p (x:xs)
 | p x = x:filter p xs
 | otherwise = filter1 p xs
```

I implemented the `map` and `filter` function ( I know it is superfluous but it practices me ) and I have a square function. Now the problem is to combine the `map` with the `filter` and I also get an `error` message at `p = (\x -> mod x 3 == 0 && x/=0)`.

My error message is `<interactive>:4:1: error: Variable not in scope : p :: Integer -> t`

Comment: What error message do you get? That definition of `p` is working fine for me in GHCi.

Comment: As for how to use `map` and `filter` to get the same result as your list comprehension - what combination have you tried? Do you know which functions to apply `map` and `filter` to?

Comment: @RobinZigmond  My error message is  <interactive>:4:1: error: Variable not in scope : p :: Integer -> t

Comment: @RobinZigmond I have not tried much yet it´s my second day with Haskell and i´m a bit  overwhelmed.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend trying to do all this in an interactive session. I think that's ultimately the cause of your out of scope error. Try moving the definitions into a file and loading it into GHCi with `:l`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have everything you need here. You wrote

```
let res = [ x^2 | x <- [0..10], mod x 2==0, x/=0 ]
```

But this means you could also write

```
let res = [ y^2 | y <- [ x | x <- [0..10] 
                           , (mod x 2==0 && x/=0) ] ]
~=
let res = [ y^2 | y <- [ x | x <- [0..10], test x ] ]
   where
   test x = (mod x 2==0 && x/=0)
~=
let res = [ y^2 | y <- baz [0..10] ]
   where
   baz xs = [ x | x <- xs, test x ]
   test x = (mod x 2==0 && x/=0)
~=
let res = [ sqr y | y <- bar test [0..10] ]
   where
   sqr y = y^2
   bar p xs = [ x | x <- xs, p x ]
   test x = (mod x 2==0 && x/=0)
~=
let res = quux ( bar test [0..10] )
   where
   quux ys = [ sqr y | y <- ys ]
   sqr y = y^2
   bar p xs = [ x | x <- xs, p x ]
   test x = (mod x 2==0 && x/=0)
~=
let res = foo sqr ( bar test [0..10] )
   where
   foo f ys = [ f y | y <- ys ]
   sqr y = y^2
   bar p xs = [ x | x <- xs, p x ]
   test x = (mod x 2==0 && x/=0)
```

So now we do have the two functions, `foo f ys` for mapping a function `f` over a list `ys`,  and `bar p xs` for testing each element of `xs` by a predicate `p` and filtering out all that fail to pass that test (i.e. all `x`s such that `p x == False`). And, it turns out, *we already had* their definitions!

All we needed to extract them from our raw code was *abstraction*.

```
let res = map sqr ( filter test [0..10] )
   where
   sqr y = y^2
   test x = (mod x 2==0 && x/=0)
```